# C Struct in Swift

Tags: c, swift

I'm attempting to use [amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c) in a Swift project however I'm unsure of how to create a [SignalingClientInfo struct](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c/blob/master/src/include/com/amazonaws/kinesis/video/webrtcclient/Include.h#L1099-L1105). Specifically I'm unsure of how to properly construct the `clientId`:

```
var signalingClientInfo = SignalingClientInfo(
    version: UINT32(SIGNALING_CLIENT_INFO_CURRENT_VERSION),
    clientId: clientId,
    loggingLevel: UINT32(1)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of annoying, but fixed-sized arrays in C like `clientId` are imported into Swift as tuples.

There's on-going discussions on adding proper fixed-size arrays to Swift, but in the mean time, there are implementation-dependent tricks you can use to construct large tuples from arrays.

See https://oleb.net/blog/2017/12/swift-imports-fixed-size-c-arrays-as-tuples/

Edit: it looks like the layout of homogeneous tuples is [guaranteed](https://forums.swift.org/t/guarantees-of-tuples-as-fixed-sized-stack-allocated-arrays/5800/3). So this is safe, just annoying.